# How to interpret a legacy ssas model?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, data-modeling

I am trying to understand a legacy data model:
[image]

I believe this is used for RLS, but isn't it redundant to have so many tables to handle it? or is this standard?

Why some relationships are bidirectional? We only want the filter to flow to the Fact, what could be a reason to have a <> relationship?

Having so many tables... Where is best to put the RLS filters? on which table?

Answer (score 0):

> I believe this is used for RLS, but isn't it redundant to have so many tables to handle it?

You have to choose between having more tables or more data for complex RLS scenarios.  You could replace the last three tables with one that has one row per project role per employee, eg

(ProjectId, ProjectRoleId, EmployeeUPN)

which is simpler at runtime, but more data and must be built during refresh.

> Why some relationships are bidirectional?

1-many always flow filters from the 1 to the many side.  Here the bidirectional relationships are needed to make the user filters flow towards the fact table.

> Where is best to put the RLS filters? on which table?

The general pattern is that you put the RLS filter on a table that has the user's UPN in it, and has filter flow to a dimension table.